# ASP.NET 5 Web Template build errors with brand new project in VS2015 CTP 6

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm not sure what's going on here. I almost wonder if I've messed up my nuget sources or something.

This is with Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6.

New Project->Select Folder->ASP.NET 5 Preview Starter Web.

It won't build due to about 20 errors. See screenshot.

Any ideas?

[Here's a link for a larger view of the errors.](https://imgur.com/liqC6jx)

[image: Selecting Template]
[image: Error List]
[image: Nuget Sources]

Comment: For what it's worth, on a clean install of CTP 6 on a fresh Windows 8.1 VM and an update to NuGet (from the Extensions and Updates item in the Tools menu), I don't have the aspnetvnext item in my list at all. The nuget.org entry (the v2 one) is there, but unchecked. I didn't have any issue building the starter project, so you might try unchecking those other two package sources and giving it another shot.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the response. I'm not sure what the issue was. I uninstalled, deleted my .k folder in my home directory, reinstalled and everything is fine. I downloaded the full ISO this time around and I noticed a couple of different things about the install process. I can't imagine that that had anything to do with it, but hey, it's working now.

Comment: I installed the Web Tools 2015 – Visual Studio 2015 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48222 and this problem was finally fixed (I won't admit how long it took to figure out).  I'm using windows 7, which might be part of the problem.